# What is a good alternative to the iDVD OneStep DVD feature for copying video from a camcorder to DVD (on Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, video, dvd, camera, authoring

I can't use the iDVD "OneStep DVD" button to copy video from my camcorder to a DVD—see "[Why does nothing happen after I press OK after selecting OneStep DVD in iDVD (with my Canon HV20 connected)?](https://superuser.com/questions/154712/why-does-nothing-happen-after-i-press-ok-after-selecting-onestep-dvd-in-idvd-wit)".  Is there another Mac OS X application (or a feature or combination of features in the iLife apps) that would allow me to easily do this?

**Update**: I tried iMovie (`09), but it seems designed for many short clips rather than a single long recording (a one-hour childrens' play in this case).  It wouldn't import the entire recording into a single clip.

**Update #2**: I guess I should try [Final Cut Express](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB278Z/A?fnode=NDQ4OTY4OA&mco=MTA5MDg2Mzk)?

Comment: two tagging notes: (1) please use the tag [osx] when referring to Mac OS X -- the tag [mac-os] is for System 9 and earlier.  (2) please use the tag [camera] to refer to video cameras as well as still cameras -- there's no need for a separate [camcorder] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Cut Express worked.  I used it to capture video from the camcorder, and export that video to a QuickTime movie, which I then burned to a DVD using iDVD.